# Convert Android.Media.Image to Android.Graphics.Bitmap using Xamarin.Android & C#

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.android

I need to convert from Android.Media.Image to Android.Graphics.Bitmap for a Xamarin.Android app using C#. Many of the answers I have found (which didn't seem to work, not to mention I had trouble understanding) mention Renderscript & ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB, but [Renderscript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.html) has been deprecated in API 31. I never used Renderscript before anyway, so the migration guide didn't help much anyway. What is the best (or actually any) way to convert from Android.Media.Image to Android.Graphics.Bitmap for a Xamarin.Android app using C#

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the bytes of the `Android.Media.Image` and convert the bytes to bitmap.

Please refer to the following code:

```
 public Bitmap ConvertMediaImageToBitMap(Android.Media.Image image)
        {
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Capacity()];
            buffer.Get(bytes);
            Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, null);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
```

Comment: I use that exact code, but the returned value is null. My image (in case it may be of significance) comes from the Analyze method of an ImageAnalysis.IAnalyzer when using a PreviewView, so the format is YUV_420_888, and the phone I am doing my testing with is a Samsung Galaxy S10e.

Comment: Have you tested on other devices? Will this problem arise?

Comment: I can't claim to have tested it on any devices other than the Samsung Galaxy S10e as mentioned, since I do not have any other devices currently available.

Comment: While looking at the Android documentation at:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy#getImage()
I noticed that it says the following:
It is possible for an ImageProxy to wrap something that isn't an Image. If that's the case then it will return null.
Is it possible that this is possible or related to my problem? Even though I have confirmed that Image is not null, I have not (and am not sure how I would) confirmed that it really is an Image (although I don't know why it wouldn't be). Is it possible that something related to this is causing the problem?

Comment: Could you please post the `image` you have used? Or how can we reproduce this problem ?

Comment: The `Image` comes from the `Image` property of the `IImageProxy` that is passed to the `Analyze` method of the `ImageAnalysis.IAnalyzer` I use for my `ImageAnalysis`

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo here so that we can test on our side?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a working solution, here is an extension method that seems to work:

```
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this Image img)
{
    ByteBuffer ybuffer = img.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
    ByteBuffer vubuffer = img.GetPlanes()[2].Buffer;
    ybuffer.Position(0);
    vubuffer.Position(0);
    int ysize = ybuffer.Remaining();
    int vusize = vubuffer.Remaining();
    byte[] nv21 = new byte[ysize + vusize];
    ybuffer.Get(nv21, 0, ysize);
    vubuffer.Get(nv21, ysize, vusize);
    YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormatType.Nv21, img.Width, img.Height, null);
    MemoryStream outstream = new MemoryStream();
    yuvimage.CompressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, yuvimage.Width, yuvimage.Height), 50, outstream);
    byte[] imagebytes = outstream.ToArray();
    return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imagebytes, 0, imagebytes.Length, null);
}
```

Take note of the `.Position(0);` statements, these are important if the method gets called more than once with the same Image. This may be a rare or unlikely scenario, but it took me a while to find so it be good to include if it does come up. Hopefully finally having a solution (with many thanks to you and other forums as well) can same everyone a lot of the frustration it took to find it.